Rank of a matrix of inner products
Consider two sets of linearly independent vectors $\left\{x^i\right\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\left\{y^j\right\}_{j=1}^n$, where $x^i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y^j\in \mathbb{R}^d$ for every $i,j$, and $n,N\leqslant d$. Let's also write the matrices with the previous vectors on the columns, that is:
\begin{equation}
    Y:=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
y^1_1 & y^2_1 & \cdots & y^n_1\\
\vdots & y^2_2 & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y^1_d& \cdots & \cdots & y^n_d
\end{array}\right],  X:=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
x^1_{1} & x^2_{1} & \cdots & x^N_{1}\\
\vdots & x^2_{2} & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x^1_{d}& \cdots & \cdots & x^N_{d}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
My question: what is the right assumption that I have to add if I want to obtain that the following matrix has rank equal $N$:
\begin{equation}
    X^TY:=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\langle x^1, y^1\rangle & \langle x^1, y^2\rangle & \cdots & \langle x^1, y^n\rangle\\
\vdots & \langle x^2, y^2\rangle & \cdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle x^N, y^1\rangle& \cdots & \cdots & \langle x^N, y^n\rangle
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
I know in this case that if the dimensions are $n\geqslant d \geqslant N$ then it is almost straightforward using Sylvester inequality, but in my setting what I have to assume in such a way that $\operatorname{rank}(X^TY)=N$? Thanks.

First of all, you need $n \leq N$ in order to have a rank of $N$

Under that assumption, you should find that $X^T Y$ has rank $N$ if and only if $\text{span}({y^j}) \cap \text{span}({x^i})^\perp = {0}$. Minimally, this requires that we have $n + N \leq d$.

I suggest you use the notation $x^{(i)}$ to denote a vector, so that it does not get confused with $i^\text{th}$ power of a scalar $x$.

Hi, thanks for the comment. Ben Grossman you said ''if and only if'', can you show me a proof or a link with something similar.

@BenGrossmann, can you provide a proof? That ''minimal'' requirement $n+N\leqslant d$ doesn't seem really correct.

@math95 What I mean by "minimally" is that the condition $n + N \leq d$ is necessary but insufficient

@BenGrossmann It still doesn't seem necessary. Suppose you have $X=Y$ and $n=N=d$ which is of course possible. Then $n+N=2d>d$ but $\operatorname{span}\left(\left{x^j\right}\right) \cap \operatorname{span}\left(\left{x^i\right}\right)^{\perp}={0}$. Please, if you can provide a proof of your comment so everything will be more clear.

@math I think I was just straightforwardly wrong about the necessary condition; the argument I had in mind doesn't work and your counterexample is correct. I'll post a proof of the earlier comment when I have the chance.

@math The correct version of what I had in mind is that we can guarantee an intersection between those spaces when $(d - N) + n > d$, which is to say that $n > N$, but this was clear in any case because the rank of an $N \times n$ matrix is at most $\min{N,n}$.

@math I also swapped which span needs the $\perp$; proof on the way

@BenGrossmann thank you so much for the proof. So from your proof it really seems that you need the linear independence of the $\left{x^i\right}{i=1}^N$ but not of the $\left{y^j\right}{j=1}^n$. Am I missing something?

@math95 That is correct

@BenGrossmann Thanks again. Sorry, I have one last question. If some of the terms in the matrix $W^TX$ become immediately zero, but I still have at least one term in every row and in every column (non zero), your argument still gives you rank equal $N$?

@math95 Yeah there's no issue with having zero-entries. Consider for instance the case where the $x$'s and $y$'s are standard basis vectors

@BenGrossmann maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I wanted to say, what if instead of the matrix $W^TX$ you have a different matrix that has some inner products like the ones in $W^TX$ and some zeros and there is at least one inner product in every row and every column. From your argument you could still say that this matrix, let's call it $M$, has rank $N$?

@math95 I see, I didn't understand what you meant by "become immediately zero". In that case, no; my argument is not sufficient.

@BenGrossmann What do you think it should be the right assumption for obtaining rank $N$ also for a such a matrix $M$?

@math95 I don't think that there is any straightforward assumption that would guarantee this outcome

@BenGrossmann Maybe something on the zeros?

@math95 There are certainly arrangements of zeros that guarantee that the matrix will NOT have rank $N$, but there's no condition over the position of the zeroed-out entries alone that will guarantee a rank of $N$. Perhaps you should post a new question about this.


Claim: $X^TY$ has rank $N$ if and only if
$$
\text{span}(\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N) \cap \text{span}(\{y^j\}_{j=1}^n)^\perp = \{0\}.
$$

Proof: We note that an $N \times n$ matrix $M$ has rank $N$ (i.e. full row-rank) if and only if its left nullspace is trivial, which is to say that the unique solution to $M^T \mathbf  c = \mathbf 0$ is $\mathbf c = \mathbf 0$.
With that in mind, suppose that $X^TY$ has rank less than $N$. Let $\mathbf c$ denote a non-zero vector in the kernel of $(X^TY)^T = Y^TX$. We see that $X \mathbf c$ is a non-zero element of $\text{span}(\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N)$, and the fact that $Y^T(X \mathbf c) = \mathbf 0$ shows us that $X \mathbf c \in \text{span}(\{y^j\}_{j=1}^n)^\perp$. Thus, there is a non-zero element in the intersection of these subspaces.
Conversely, every element of the $\text{span}(\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N)$ can be written in the form $X \mathbf c$ for some vector $\mathbf c$. If a non-zero vector $X \mathbf c$ is in $\text{span}(\{y^j\}_{j=1}^n)^\perp$, then $Y^T(X \mathbf c) = \mathbf 0$ so that $\mathbf c$ is in the left nullspace of $X^TY$.
The conclusion follows.
